Batch extraction of attachments via ArcGIS Pro
I have a hosted feature layer of about 20k items with attached photos. I'm trying to find a way to batch download the attached photos so I have access to them on a local device. At the moment the only way I can seem to find to save attachments to file is to click on each feature and use the attachment manager to save the file(s). This is very tedious and slow. Is there a faster way to do this?

You could use the ArcGIS API for Python with its AttachmentManager module.  See:  https://developers.arcgis.com/python/latest/api-reference/arcgis.features.managers.html#attachmentmanager .  Some examples of using it for this purpose are at:  https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-api-for-python-questions/using-attachmentmanager-to-download-attachments/td-p/1061943
